# create scatter plot matrix with openair and hexbin

Tags: r, openair

I've worked with the `openair` and `hexbin` packages to create two scatter plots with the help of the scatter plot function commands:

```r
scatterPlot(mydata, x ="Observed" , y = "Model1",xlab=10, ylab=10,method = "hexbin",mod.line=T,auto.text=F, col = "jet", xbin = 30)

scatterPlot(mydata, x ="Observed" , y = "Model2",xlab=10, ylab=10,method = "hexbin",mod.line=T,auto.text=F, col = "jet", xbin = 30)
```

I've got the scatter plots, but if I want to put them into one plot and with one color counts to get something similar to this:How should i proceed?

[please refer to this link to view the image : https://ibb.co/rF148kp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FGiun.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could reorganize your data frame so that it has three columns - "Observed", "Modeled", and "Model Type". Example -

```
structure(list(observed = c(2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 
10L, 12L, 12L, 14L, 14L, 16L, 16L, 18L, 18L, 20L, 20L), modelled = c(1L, 
5L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 9L, 13L, 15L, 16L, 14L, 18L, 17L, 10L, 21L, 26L, 
24L, 22L, 28L, 27L, 30L), model_type = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L), .Label = c("Model 1", "Model 2"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-20L))
```

This way, you can then use the following code -

```
scatterPlot(mydata, x = "observed", y = "modelled", type = c("model_type"),
        method = "hexbin",mod.line=T,auto.text=F, col = "jet", xbin = 5,
        linear = TRUE, layout = c(2, 1))
```

To create a plot containing the two scatter plots. Note, the above code sets xbin to 5 purely for the reason that I have used a small data set for testing purposes. Also, excuse the spelling error in the y-axis and code ("modelled" should be "modeled")!

[image: Scatter plots on one plot]